# integer validation in django not working

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

forms.py

```
class UserCreateProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fields = ['phone_daytime', 'phone_mobile']

    def clean(self):
        cd=self.cleaned_data
        validate_integer(cd.get('phone_daytime', None))
        validate_integer(cd.get('phone_mobile', None))
        return cd

     def validate_integer(phone_daytime,phone_mobile):
    try:
        int(phone_daytime,phone_mobile)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        raise ValidationError('Phone number must be number')
```

I want to validate the form with two phone number field.

The above one is not working,not throwing any error but not functioning.

The field should not accept alphabet,special character and blank also allowed.How to do this validation.

Thanks

Comment: How is your `validate_integer()` implemented?

Comment: Is validate_integer a built-in function?

Comment: What about `-`? Can that not be in a phone number?

Comment: @limelights validate_integer() method is updated in question

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Yeah I would definetly use this. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/localflavor/ Phone fields are already implemented there for a lot of countries, surely yours too.

For India:

> Validates that the data is a valid Indian phone number, including the
>   STD code. It's normalised to 0XXX-XXXXXXX or 0XXX XXXXXXX format. The
>   first string is the STD code which is a '0' followed by 2-4 digits.
>   The second string is 8 digits if the STD code is 3 digits, 7 digits if
>   the STD code is 4 digits and 6 digits if the STD code is 5 digits. The
>   second string will start with numbers between 1 and 6. The separator
>   is either a space or a hyphen.

```
import re

phone_digits_re = re.compile(r"""
(
(?P<std_code> # the std-code group
^0 # all std-codes start with 0
(
(?P<twodigit>\d{2}) | # either two, three or four digits
(?P<threedigit>\d{3}) | # following the 0
(?P<fourdigit>\d{4})
)
)
[-\s] # space or -
(?P<phone_no> # the phone number group
[1-6] # first digit of phone number
(
(?(twodigit)\d{7}) | # 7 more phone digits for 3 digit stdcode
(?(threedigit)\d{6}) | # 6 more phone digits for 4 digit stdcode
(?(fourdigit)\d{5}) # 5 more phone digits for 5 digit stdcode
)
)
)$""", re.VERBOSE)
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/django/django-localflavor-in/blob/master/django_localflavor_in/forms.py).

In your model:

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class YourProfileModel(Model):
    phone_field = CharField(max_lenght=12, validators=[RegexValidator(regex=phone_digits_re)])
```

Comment: but they dont want to add even validator.

Comment: @karthikr That was the documentation example, was still editing my answer. thx

Comment: I got that. But there is no inbuilt validate_integer validator. You would have to implement it. Guess that is already done - thats y the OP is not getting any errors

Comment: Of course, but he's already using a function on his code. It seems he already has that.

Comment: Yes,the link what you mentioned is very useful,but at this moment i need to validate int only,how to do.

Comment: @MonkL copy the regex from the repo of your country, where are you from?

Comment: @MonkL There, that should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

For validation of a phone number this is the approach you should take.

```
class UserCreateProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fields = ['phone_daytime', 'phone_mobile']

    def clean(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        validate_phonenumber(cd.get('phone_daytime', None))
        validate_phonenumber(cd.get('phone_mobile', None))
        return cd

    def validate_phonenumber(phone_number):
        for char in phone_number:
            if not char.isdigit():
                raise ValidationError("Phone number must be number")
```

The error you had in your code was that you tried to do `int(phone_daytime, phone_mobile)`.
This is not correct, this throws a `TypeError()`.
Also what you did removes the leading `0`from the phone number. Now that wasn't as bad since you didn't use the parsed number anyways but good to know.

Comment: I am getting this error "global name 'validate_phonenumber' is not defined"